# Cannot read property 'find' of undefined while Finding Data

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose, schema

Getting an Error!

I have no idea what to do, please help me in Solving the Error

Error:-
The Error shows that find is undefined

```
{"message":"Cannot read property 'find' of undefined"}
```

post.js

Controllers

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const { Restaurant } = require('../models/restaurantsSchema')

const getPosts = (req,res) => {
    res.status(200).send('Hi, their')
}

const api = async (req,res) => {
    try {
        const sample_restaurants = await Restaurant.find()

        res.status(200).json(sample_restaurants)

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json({ message: error.message })
    }
}

module.exports = {
    getPosts,
    api,
}
```

Schema

I have create Schema here

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const restaurantsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    address : Object,
    grades : Array,
    name : String,
    borough : String,
    cuisine : String,
    restaurant_id : String,
})

var Restaurant = mongoose.model('Restaurant', restaurantsSchema);

module.exports = Restaurant;
```

Comment: Please specify the error as well.

Comment: `Restaurant` is undefined. Can you add the content of `restaurantsSchema` in the question ?

Answer (score 0):

- I have noticed that in module.exports if there are only two elements then why putting comma after api i.e

```
module.exports = {
  getPosts,
  api
}
```

this may be helpful for you.